# ReactJS How to handle object's methods in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the Google Maps API and I have this following piece of code -

```
      class App extends React.Component {
          state = {
               polygon: null,
           };

          checkPoly() {
             if (this.state.polygon) {
               this.state.polygon.setMap(null);
               this.setState({
                  polygon: null
                });
              }
           }

          initPoly(evt) {
            let polygon = evt.overlay;
            polygon.setEditable(true);
            this.setState({
                polygon: polygon
            });
           }
      }
```

The thing is I am confused as to how to pass the value to the object's method in the state particularly this line `this.state.polygon.setMap(null)`. I don't know if I am doing things the right way but it works though. Can you tell me if I am using the state correctly as per ReactJS conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I would recommend is to remove this line:

```
this.state.polygon.setMap(null);
```

This is a state-mutation which is highly discouraged in React. This almost always leads to unintended behaviour in your component. But in your case, since you are following-up with

```
this.setState({
    polygon: null
});
```

which seeks to accomplish the same thing, the effects are unnoticeable. Otherwise, your code seems fine as is.

To create a copy of your polygon object you could do something like this

```
const polygon = {...this.state.polygon}
```

Then you can make your desired updates to the object methods from there :)

Comment: Thanks but how do I pass value to the object's method in the state? Consider I didn't set the state to null in the next line then what should I replace the line this.state.polygon.setMap(null) with? Do I need to make a shallow copy or something?

Comment: @FatehAK Just wondering, if you plan on setting polygon to null in that line anyway, what is the point of changing the objects.setMap method to null before it? :)   But to answer your question, yes you would create a copy of it instead of updating the initial state directly.

Comment: The thing is this is just part of my code and I got other objects where I am not setting the object directly to null. How would you create a copy I came across this - `var newMyObj = Object.assign({}, this.state.myObject, {
  prop1: event.target.value
}); ` but that only updates the property so how do I pass in a value to the object's function?

Comment: @FatehAK oh I see! i just updated my answer to show you how to make a copy of the object. This way you can freely update its object methods without worrying about state-mutation.

Comment: @FatehAK you're very wlecome